# How to update string with special char (%,& etc) from a textarea to a mysql table?

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and java.
I am trying to update my mysql table with text from a textarea of an HTML form.
I am using below code to update it :

```
Statement st = con.createStatement();           
qs = "INSERT INTO pvr_feasibiliyu_coments ( pvr_number, confname, external_coment) VALUES(?, ?, ?);";  

PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(qs);
preparedStatement.setString(1, request.getParameter("pnum"));
preparedStatement.setString(2, request.getParameter("cnfname"));
preparedStatement.setString(3, request.getParameter("coment"));
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

SQL update is not happening if the text entered in the textarea contains %,&' and + .
I would like to update table with all the text entered in the textarea.
Please help.

Comment: what is your server language?

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely different things. What are you using?

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to scape special characters with '\':

http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/javascript_escape_characters.cfm

Answer (score 0):

find and replace the respective special characters with escape character `\`

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like Java, not JavaScript, so I'll treat this as a java question.

Prepared statements should eliminate the need to escape special characters for your query, so I'll look for other possible reasons.

Your field `pvr_number` looks like it expects a numerical value, not a string (just a guess, there is no way of telling until you update your post with your table definition). If it is a numerical field, e.g. `int`, you need to use `setInt()` instead of `setString()` on your `preparedStatement`.

Comment: pvr_number is a string field.field i am facing issue with is external_coment which is a VARCHAR.

Comment: please discard this question.
issue was with the not encoding text before transferring using jquery ajax which is fixed now.

Thanks.
Ratheesh

Comment: Then post your solution as an answer, maybe it will help someone else in the future.